# Multiple characters in a character constant

Tags: c

> Some C compilers permit multiple characters in a character constant.
>   This means that writing 'yes' instead of "yes" may well go undetected.
>   Source: C traps and pitfalls

Can anyone give an example of this where multiple characters are allowed in a character constant?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Code Monkey cited, it is implementation defined and implementation varies -- it isn't just a BigEndian/LittleEndian and charset difference.  I've tested four implementations (all using ASCII) with the program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned value = 'ABCD';
    char* ptr = (char*)&value;

    printf("'ABCD' = %02x%02x%02x%02x = %08x\n", ptr[0], ptr[1], ptr[2], ptr[3], value);
    value = 'ABC';
    printf("'ABC'  = %02x%02x%02x%02x = %08x\n", ptr[0], ptr[1], ptr[2], ptr[3], value);
    return 0;
}
```

and I got four different results

Big endian (AIX, POWER, IBM compiler)

```
'ABCD' = 41424344 = 41424344
'ABC'  = 00414243 = 00414243
```

Big endian (Solaris, Sparc, SUN compiler)

```
'ABCD' = 44434241 = 44434241
'ABC'  = 00434241 = 00434241
```

Little endian (Linux, x86_64, gcc)

```
'ABCD' = 44434241 = 41424344
'ABC'  = 43424100 = 00414243
```

Little endian (Solaris, x86_64, Sun compiler)

```
'ABCD' = 41424344 = 44434241
'ABC'  = 41424300 = 00434241
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use it in a case statement, I guess, but I wouldn't recommend it.

`'yes'` is a multicharacter constant.  Its type is `int`, and its value is implementation dependent. So like you already stated, it's up to the compiler.

so `int foo = 'yes';`

*ARM, section 2.5.2, page 9:*

> "A character constant is one or more characters enclosed in single
>   quotes, as in 'x'."

Later on the same page:

> "Multicharacter constants have type int.  The value of a
>   multicharacter constant is implementation dependent.  For example, the
>   value of 'AB' could reasonably be expected to be 'A' 'B' and
>   ('A'<<8)+'B' on three different implementations.  Multicharacter
>   constants are usually best avoided."

and

Quoting from the ANSI C specification (to which C++ makes some attempt to be compatible):

> 3.1.3.4  Character Constants Semantics
>
> An integer charcter constant has type int [note that it has type char
>   in C++]...The value of an integer character constant containing more
>   than one character...is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 7):

Multi-character constants are *allowed* in all contexts where single-character constants are allowed.

As for where they'd actually be used, I've seen code that uses multi-character constants to create legible unique values.  For example, assuming that int is 4 bytes, 'ABCD' and 'EFGH' are likely to be distinct.  (This isn't guaranteed by the language; the implementation must document the mapping, but it needn't be reasonable.)  And assuming a reasonable mapping, you'll likely see "ABCD" or "EFGH" in the object code.  Not the best idea in the world, but it can work if you don't care much about portability.

Incidentally, *all* conforming C compilers support multi-character constants (by definition; a compiler that doesn't support them is non-conforming).