# Bitoperation results not as expected

Tags: c, bit

Here is this simple code:

```
char a = '10';
char b = '6';
printf("%d\n", a | b);
printf("%d\n", a ^ b);
printf("%d\n", a << 2);
```

and the output is

```
54
6
192
```

Now my question is, why these results. I checked it on paper and what I have is

```
1110 for a | b = 14
1100 for a ^ b = 12
00101000 for a << 2 = 40
```

So why this different result?

Comment: Hint: Try `printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);`. I think you meant `char a = 10; char b = 6;`

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring:

```
char a = '10';
char b = '6';
```

In this case `b` is `00110110` (`0x36`) because you are declaring a character, not an integer.

I also don't know why `char a = '10';` even works because single quotes (`'`) are used to create only single chars literals and you're declaring two there.

The correct way should be:

```
char a = 10;
char b = 6;
printf("%d\n", a | b);
printf("%d\n", a ^ b);
printf("%d\n", a << 2);
```

Comment: Side note: Some compilers accept integer "multi-character constants" , but they are highly compiler/platform dependent. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944730/multiple-characters-in-a-character-constant.

Comment: Yes I assumed that. Thanks for clearing it up for me.

Comment: So what is the bit-repr of '10' then?

Comment: @Saphire no idea lol :D. I don't know how the compiler will handle this.

Comment: For completeness sake, multi-character constants are implementation-defined, but conforming compilers are required to handle them. Character literals have type `int` and usually compilers map the characters of a multi-character constant to bytes in the `int`. Take a look here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944730/multiple-characters-in-a-character-constant

Comment: @Saphire it's probably 0x3130 or 12592, but since you assign it to a `char` it gets truncated to 0x30 or 48.

Answer (score 2):

You solved this on paper for `int` `10` and `6` not for `char`s `'10' = 49 or 48` (interpretation of multi-character constant is compiler dependent) and `'6' = 54`.

Comment: How the multi-character constant `'10'` is interpreted is highly compiler-dependent. For example with Clang on OS X, it is `= 48`, i.e. the first character is ignored.

Comment: Why 49? How did you calculate that?

Comment: Both are correct @haccks,saphire
Its totally compiler dependant. Mostly compilers will interpret this assignment from right to left but some compilers from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you defined the variables as character(char) but in the notebook 
you are calculating the result by treating them as Integer(int)
If you want the correct answer try this code and check -

```
int a = 10; 
int b = 6;
printf("%d\n", a | b);
printf("%d\n", a ^ b);
printf("%d\n", a << 2);
```