# What's wrong with this switch statement?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMBdw.jpg)

As you can see from the output, the switch statement completely skips over case 'view1'. And I'm having trouble understanding what the warnings mean.

Comment: You're passing a single char into the function, it can never be the same as a multi character string.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson oh, can it be changed to multi-char?

Comment: I suggest using `NSString*` as a parameter type (constants are then declared as `@"view1"`). Even then, I don't think there's a possibility to use `switch` to compare them.

Comment: I think if-else would be better for string comparisons

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yeh I tried using NSString instead but it doesn't work with switch statements :(

Comment: what kind of data type is 'view1' in your example?

Comment: use `if ([view isEqualToString:@"view1"]) {}`

Comment: You can't have multiple characters between single quotes. Single quotes denote a char, which is always one character, not a string. Furthermore, strings in switch statements are generally not a good idea (you'll be comparing references instead of values).

Comment: Some compilers (including gcc and clang) permit up to *four* characters in a constant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944730/multiple-characters-in-a-character-constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the method signature to

```
- (void)switchViewTo:(NSString *)view 
{
  if ([view isEqualToString:@"view1"]) {
    NSLog(@"view 1");
  } else if ([view isEqualToString:@"view2"]) {
    NSLog(@"view 2");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"whatever");
  }
}
```

In the designated initializer you call `[self switchToView:@"view1"];`