# C++: Replace character in a string with more than one number?

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to replace a single character in a string with more than one number. Lets make it quick:

```
replace(string.begin(), string.end(), 'a', '1');
```

^ **WORKS!** ^

```
replace(string.begin(), string.end(), 'a', '11');
```

or

```
replace(string.begin(), string.end(), 'a', "1");
```

^ **DOESN'T WORK!** ^

How do I do it? Is there any function for it?

***NOTE:***
I'm not asking how to:

- Replace part of a string with another string
- Replace substring withanother substring

Comment: Aside: `'11'` is a multi-character-literal, having type `int`. It is most likely not remotely what you think it is.

Comment: And BTW, this question is not even a part of those 'already answered' questions! Can you people even read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some overloaded member function `replace` of class `std::basic_string` instead of the standard algorithm `std::replace`.

For example

```
for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0;
      ( pos = s.find( 'a', pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
      pos += 2 )
{
   s.replace( pos, 1, 2, '1' );
}
```

Or if the number can be any arbitrary string then you can write

```
std::string number( "123" );
for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0;
      ( pos = s.find( 'a', pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
      pos += number.size() )
{
   s.replace( pos, 1, number );
}
```

If you want to replace a number with a character then you can write

```
for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0;
      ( pos = s.find( "11", pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
      ++pos )
{
   s.replace( pos, 2, 1, 'a' );
}
```

Comment: The first one works! Thanks alot man! :)

Comment: Emm... how can I do it in reverse? Like number to alphabet? Example: 'a' to 123 then 123 to 'a'?

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Marwan Ansari See my updated post. In general you should use together member functions find and replace of class std::string.

Answer (score -1):

You need to give the same type of argument as the value to be replaced and the replacing value.

`'a'` is a `char`, while `"1"` is a string. You can't mix those two, `replace` in this case only supports `char`s.

Note: `'11'` is not a valid char.

Comment: That explains why the OP's approach doesn't work. But he was asking for a way to achieve what he wants.

Comment: Regarding your edit: `'11'` might be valid for certain implementations. [See this question for example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6944730/1451714).

Comment: @lethal-guitar It's of type `int` and not of type `char`.

Comment: @AdamS fair enough. Still, it will possibly compile without error. I'd add that it is a "multi-character literal".