# C: enum with string values

Tags: c, enums

What kind of enum is this and what is its purpose?

```
enum {
        kAudioFormatLinearPCM = 'lpcm',
        kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 = 'ima4'
};
```

Comment: `'lpcm'` isn't a "string". A "string" would be `"lpcm"`. Mind the **double** quotes in the latter case.

Comment: It's actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944730/multiple-characters-in-a-character-constant

Comment: Not of the one that it's marked as.