# How to check, which (ASCII) code was used for Line Feed in a simple text file?

Tags: c, parsing, text, input, ascii

I'd like to parse a simple text file in a `.c`-program, where I want to react on all the `line feeds` in it. Unfortunately checking it with "`is character == \n`" does not work always.

I know there are different methods to *code* a line feed (e.g. 0x0A in ASCII code), so my question is: is there a safe way to check whether a character is `LF` or not?

Comment: `if c == 10` ? Chars are basically ints

Comment: "is character == \n" does not work always. why?

Comment: @Sathish idk. It's catching a clear line feed and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Why do you ask? Why does it matter?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I need a save method, that catches all the possible line feeds and not just some

Comment: You can check for `character == '\n' || character == '\r\n'`

Comment: @Himanshu: no you cannot: [Multiple characters in a character constant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944730/multiple-characters-in-a-character-constant)

Comment: sry, @Jongware yes you are right, that will be two character. he has to check '\r' first than '\n'

Comment: I see. There seemed to be some confusion. `Line Feed (LF,\n) != Carriage Return (CR,\r)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end-of-line marker is operating system specific. On some OSes it is just `\n`, on others it may be `\r` or a mixture like  `\r\n` etc. Probably the form-feed `\f` might sometimes be considered as an end-of-line.

On some systems, not passing the `b` mode flag to [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) is altering the way it is read by the OS. On these systems, the file is then opened in binary mode with `b` and in text mode without it (and the text mode may mean to interpret end-of-line differently). You could also use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) and handle the terminating characters as spaces (e.g. use [isspace(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isspace.3.html)...)

BTW, on Linux the [dos2unix(1)](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) command might be useful.

Also, your app might get a textual file produced on some other OS (without conversion). I would use `getline` (or the old [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) if you don't care about very long lines) and handle all the spaces characters (tab, newline, formfeed, return, etc...) the same (like [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html) or `sscanf`  does).

I can't understand why the real end-of-line marker matters to you; why can't you use `getline` (or perhaps `fgets`) and handle every "end-of-line" character (be it `\n`, `\r`, `\f` or some mix of them) equally (in other words, as space tested with `isspace`). And this handles the case of a text file edited on Windows or MacOSX and passed to Linux or vice-versa.

Comment: is there a standard-query that'll catch them all ?

Comment: well is there a list for all the possibilities to set a LF ? To at least hard code them in a query ?

Comment: first of all thanks for your help. The problem is I need to exchange the `\n` with a different character and if there are more than 1 characters for LF (like \r\n), I feel it's getting pretty ugly to catch them all and obtain the rest of the characters of the text unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

Ok here is a list of newlines per operating system type:

Linux Systems:
    LF - LF (Line feed, '\n', 0x0A, 10 in decimal)

Unix Systems:
    LF - LF (Line feed, '\n', 0x0A, 10 in decimal)

Windows Systems:
    CR followed by LF (CR+LF, '\r\n', 0x0D0A)

Mac OS Systems:
    LF:    Line Feed, U+000A

Android Systems:
    LF - LF (Line feed, '\n', 0x0A, 10 in decimal)

Unicode Systems:
The Unicode standard defines a number of characters that conforming applications should recognize as line terminators:[3]

```
LF:    Line Feed, U+000A
VT:    Vertical Tab, U+000B
FF:    Form Feed, U+000C
CR:    Carriage Return, U+000D
CR+LF: CR (U+000D) followed by LF (U+000A)
NEL:   Next Line, U+0085
LS:    Line Separator, U+2028
PS:    Paragraph Separator, U+2029
```

Based on:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: I think it's about time to have a method that catches them all or upside down - prints according to the OS the right symbol. Thanks for your help I'd like to give both of you the right answer.

Comment: This list shows you cannot use one single method for all *possible* files. On reading an unknown file, you can easily distinguish single `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n`, but how would you know when a *double* LFs signifies a *single* line end? Even if you scan the entire file before deciding, you can't be sure.

Answer (score 2):

try to use `\r\n` rather then `\n`  .
the ASCII code of `\n` = 10 and ASCII code of `\r` = 13. so In simple text file the line feed is the combination of \r\n (carriage return and new line).

Comment: That works fine as long as you only care about Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just opening as text file, and relying on the standard library's built-in conversions to handle this. Just read lines using `fgets()` and you should be fine.

Comment: I know there are many workarounds, but I need a safe method that catches them all somehow