# Why the answer of "printf("%d", '0/');" is 12335?

Tags: c, ascii

This is the c code:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d", '0/');
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 12335! Then I try to replace '0/' with '00' and '000', and the outputs change to 12336 and 3158064, while 12336=48*(1+2^8), 3158064=48*(1+2^8+2^16). However, I still don't know why. What happens when '0/' is transformed to an integer for output?

PS: My computer is MBP, and the operating system is OS X 10.9.5 (13F34). The compiler is Apple LLVM 6.0.

Comment: Even though a basic question, I would have given a +1 for a nearly well-formed first time question if OP had added one more thing: the expected output.  Consider that for future questions.

Answer (score 3):

You have constructed a "multi-character literal".  The behaviour is implementation-defined, but in your case, the integer value is constructed from the ASCII values (12235 == 48 * 256 + 47).

Answer (score 2):

`'0/'` is a multi-character constant, which means it has an implementation-defined value. In your case, the ASCII value of the characters is `0x30 0x2f`. These are combined into `0x302f`, which equals 12335.

Answer (score 2):

Because `0/` is a multi-character constant of type `int`. You initialize the first part of a 2x3 buffer with it, and pass it to `printf` to be re-interpreted as an `int`, the first byte `'0'` is multiplied by 256 and then the second byte `'/'` is added to it. This produces the value that you see:

```
printf("%d %d %d", '0', '/', '0'*256+'/');
```

prints

```
48 47 12335
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/KJBITR).

Note that this behavior is system-dependent. On other systems you could see `12080` instead of `12335`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6944730/335858) for more information on multicharacter constants.

Comment: @ouah You're right, multi-character character literal is an `int`.