# Array of character pointers pointed to single quoted strings prints last 4 bytes of string

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c-strings, character-arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
      char *value[] = {'Godnull'};
      printf("%s\n",value);
      return 0;
}
```

Output:
llun

Could someone please explain this output.

Comment: Does
not
compile. http://ideone.com/eqFEqm

Comment: I think it should start by having you explain what this does: `char *value[] = {'Godnull'};`

Comment: `char *value[]` and `char value[]` is different. Probably you have  missed this point.

Comment: This is Undefined Behavior. The output can be anything!

Comment: I get no output: http://ideone.com/X0Kv3F  Answer:  UB

Comment: @2501 - It will compile if you choose 'C' instead of `C99`.

Comment: Did you check the compiler warnings?

Comment: I just tried this code.I get compiler warnings but ignored them.But guys,could you please let me know how 'Godnull' is stored in memory in this case.Does it have something to do with 4 byte/8 byte pointer sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a string in single quotes is absolutely fine in C. These are called **"MultiCharacter
Constant"** which is of Type ***"int"***. And depends on the compiler int will be having size of
**4 Bytes** which can store  4(1 Byte Characters) into your array. Probably that might be the 
reason why you are getting only four characters printed on the console. Please refer this [Multiple characters in a character constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944730/multiple-characters-in-a-character-constant)

Anyhow it is not suggested to declare the  array of character pointers as above.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems here:

```
 char *value[] = {'Godnull'};
```

You are creating an array of strings, when I'm assuming that you are attempting to create a single string

Additionally, to initialize a string, you want the string in double-quotes:

```
  char *value = "Godnull";
```

**Edit:**
If you really want to declare this as a character array and use it as a string, try:

```
 char value[] = {'G', 'o', 'd', 'n', 'u', 'l', 'l', '\0'};
```