# can't compare getchar != '/n' , get warning: multi-character character constant

Tags: c, getchar

When I compare  getchar() != '/n' I get the warning: multi-character character constant. I wounder why? I code in C and use gcc as compiler. I thought that getchar read in one character and converted it to int for itself. So what's the meaning of multi-character character constant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple characters in a character constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944730/multiple-characters-in-a-character-constant)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'/n' is 2 characters I think you are looking for '\n'

Getchar() will get 1 char '/n' is 2 characters (and because you defined the characters already it is a constant) so it is a multiple character character constant

Answer (score 0):

'/n' is two characters / and n. Hence multi character.
getchar reads one character at a time.
i think you want to use line break which is '\n'.