# C define string as char

Tags: c

Is it possible to define a string as char in C like this? I think C calls it multi character constant.

```
#define OK '_/'
```

I want C to treat '_/' as a char from now on, not a string, so this:

```
printf("%c", OK);
```

prints _/ and not /

Comment: An apple is an apple is an apple and not a pear.

Comment: unless you #define apple pear

Answer (score 2):

Multi character constants are of `int` type and their value is not strictly defined-- it's platform dependent stuff. So using them as normal letters is not best idea, even though you can use them in every context as normal char there is no guarantee that they will be compiled as you intend (as in your example you get only last char from ur string).
here you have explanation of the topic:
[Multiple characters in a character constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944730/multiple-characters-in-a-character-constant)

Answer (score 2):

While it is technically valid C to define `OK` as `'_/'`, the value of a multi-character character constant is implementation defined, so this is probably not something you want to do.

There is no way you will be able to print more than one character without resorting to strings.