# How do I write an integer into a text file using putw() function in C?

Tags: c, file-handling

I tried this code:

```
int main(void)
{
   FILE *fp;    // Assuming fp is initialized
   putw(11,fp);  /* Instead of writing 11 to the file this statement
                    wrote an unwanted character into the file */

   /* However when I put 11 in single quotes as,
   putw('11', fp);
   It worked properly and wrote integer 11 into the file */
}
```

What is the explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: You didn't really try this. That program crashes due to an uninitialized `fp`.

Comment: Your `putw('11',fp);` can only have "worked properly" if your `int` is 16 bits. My 32-bit `int` created a file size 4 containing `31 31 00 00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`putw('11',fp);` isn't a valid character constant, it worked only by coincident. Also if you compile the source with gcc with proper flags, it will warn you about it:

```
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
```

If you want to write the integer with text format, use `fprintf`:

```
fprintf(fp, "%d", 11);
```

If you want to write the integer in binary format, use `fwrite` or `putw` in the right way:

```
int n = 11;
fwrite(&n, sizeof n, 1, fp);
```

or

```
putw(n, fp);
```

Comment: `'11'` does not work "by coincident" although I only became aware of it through these pages. `int i = '1234';` initialises a value `0x31323334` but I can't quote a source, sorry. You received a warning, not an error.

Comment: @WeatherVane It is not conforming C, the result of `int i = '1234';` is implementation defined, so it is not portable and different compliers might give you different result. That's why the warning.

Comment: Thanks, it is [covered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944730/multiple-characters-in-a-character-constant) but implementation-defined rather than undefined.

Answer (score 3):

`putw()` writes a "word" which is a binary `int` into the `FILE`.  It does not *format* the int, it just writes it.  Same as `fwrite()` with `sizeof(int)`.

You might consider fprintf() instead:

```
fprintf(fp, "%d", 11);
```

With your old code, the file will contain four bytes like `00 00 00 0B` or `0B 00 00 00` depending on the endian mode of your system.  Or maybe eight bytes if you have a 64-bit `int` platform.  With the new code it will write two bytes always: `31 31` (that's two hex ASCII codes for `'1'`).