# String ends in /UN after receival in a c program?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am transmitting and receiving between a terminal on my phone and a bluetooth module connected to a microcontroller (pic18f).

I set up an array of 4, `char input[4] = ""` to store the user input from the terminal. The function `getsUSART(input,4)` places input in there.

The problem is, when I check what is in input, I see that this is 'ABC/UN' when I type ABC in the terminal. Is /UN an escape sequence? If so, what key is it for?

Also, if I'd like to compare input to a string, let's say the string is 'hey'
would I do `char str1[4] = "hey/UN"` and then  `strcmp(input, str1) == 0`?

Edit:

So the compiler library (USART) can be accessed here, page 66 I believe: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPLAB_C18_Libraries_51297f.pdf

This is the relevant code, just for getting the input and putting null:

```
    char input[4] = "";
    while(BusyUSART());
    while (!DataRdyUSART());
    getsUSART(input, 4);            //Get the input. 
    // NULL terminate the string for putsUSART call.
    input[4] = '/0'; 
    putrsUSART("Input:");
    putsUSART(input);
```

I am trying to null terminate it when I do input[4] =  '/0', am I doing something wrong here if it isn't null terminating?

Comment: Can you please put your whole program with the definitions of all functions like getsUSART.

Comment: Most likely your string is not null terminated, and `/UN` is just arbitrary memory contents. Please show your source code and documentation for `getsUSART`.

Comment: @Retr0id Okay I've added it in. I try to null terminate by input[4] = '/0'

Comment: `'/0'` is not valid C. Read your compiler's warnings/errors

Comment: And `input[4]` is beyond the stated range for `input`. (Which is `0..3`.)

Comment: When I compile it doesn't give me any warnings or errors on that line..? How would I null terminate a string in this case then? So should I make my null terminate be at input[3] usr256? Arrays confuse me like hell... If I can only use 0 to 3 then what exactly is 4 there for?

Comment: @Retr0id Technically, `'/0'` _is_ valid C (see [Multiple characters in a character constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6944730/2096401)), it's just that what happens is (a) implementation defined and (b) for any plausible implementation, not what the OP wants.

Comment: @TripeHound wow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting C counts from 0.

So in your example:

```
   input[0] = 'A'
   input[1] = 'B'
   input[2] = 'C'
   input[3] = some old byte of data
   input[4] = '\0'
```

Comment: Not to mention having `/0` instead of `\0`.

Comment: So if I want to take in 3 characters, I would just need input[3]..? And input[3] = '\0'? But I am getting "null-terminated initializer string too long" when I try to do char str1[3] = "ABC", so what's happening here?

Comment: You seem to be conflating many problems. "ABC" requires 4 bytes of storage, because of the null terminator.

Comment: @Lukali No, you'd need `input[4]` so there are three "boxes" for characters (`input[0]`, `input[1]` and `input[2]`) and one for the terminating `'\0'` (`input[3]`) -- four in total.

Comment: @TripeHound Thanks you made it so much clearer. I thought input[3] meant that there was 0,1,2,3 so 4 inputs. I see my mistake now.